# Letras acentuadas retornando caractere inválido

Tags: lua

Bom, percebi que em Lua, não é possível usar letras com acento.

```
print("á")
```

Retorna um caractere invalido.
Tem algum jeito de evitar isso?

Comment: Qual o sistema que está usando? Isso está muito mais relacionado ao seu sistema do que a linguagem em si. Por exemplo se testar no Codepad ou até mesmo em algumas calculadoras com suporte à Lua obterá da forma desejada: `á`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

E totalmente possivel, mas precisas definir o locale adequado. Para o efeito podes fazer uso da função [`os.setlocale (locale \[, category\])`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.setlocale) que vai definir o locale para o programa:

**Exemplo:**

```
os.setlocale("pt_PT")
```

ou

```
os.setlocale("pt_PT.iso88591")
```

Podes ver o exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Kbx3mM).

Se nenhum for definido, o do sistema é utilizado.